# writing to mongodb succeeds, but server shuts down with errors

Tags: node.js, mongoose

where can I read into errors generated by the node console and in my browser, so i can learn from them?
for example, browser console says **net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** and my node server throws errors at me about mongoose etc.

node error: 
        ......./node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:419
            throw err;
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function

node code

```
    app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
    todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : true
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        todo.find(function(err, todos){
            if(err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: And what's the error you get in the Node console, and where's the code that throws the error

Comment: In the callback to `create` log `typeof todo`, something tells me it's not a model and that it has no `find` method

Comment: i defined todo a bit before:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var todo = mongoose.model('todo', {
    text : String
});`

and in app.get i use the same todo.find to get all of my entries.
the reason i am really stuck is that when i make the find outside the callback, its works perfectly, however, finding is done before posting, therefore the find wont include the new entry. putting the find inside the callback however results in an error :/

Comment: It doesn't matter what you defined before, the callback function has an argument named `todo` that overrides whatever you've defined before, and that argument is not a model

Comment: I changed the callback argument's name to "iHopeThisWorks" and guess what, it works.
I had no idea it would overwrite it. thank you so much man for the patience and ridiculous fast replies !!!!!!! add your comment as an answer man, i'll mark it answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument in the callback for `create` has the same name as the model, overwriting the higher scoped variable `todo` with the result of the `create` function, which is not a model, and has no `find` method.

Rename the `todo` argument

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
    todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : true
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) res.send(err);

        todo.find(function(err, todos){
            if(err)
                res.send(err)

            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});
```